# Why the layout is different between storyboard and the simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

As below image shows, in the storyboard, I put a UIScrollView (say called A) under navigation bar and another UIScrollView (say called B) inside A. B is at the top of A.

However, in the simulator, there is big margin between B and the up bound of A (I didn't use any autolayout or write any code). Can anyone tell me the reason? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try setting translucent property of the navigation bar in storyboard to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the below line in your - (void)viewDidLoad method

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

hope it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're not using Auto-layout, you have Auto-layout checked on in your Storyboard. Because you do, `UIScrollViews` and any Subclasses of it (`UITableView`, `UICollectionView`, etc.) all automatically adjust for the `UINavigationBar` height when in a `UINavigationController`. This is implicit and there's no way to turn it off. The only solution is to "offset the offset" or to move the `UIScrollView` away from the `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me more about how to "offset the offset", do you mean I should set the B with a negative y-offset the same to A's y-offset?

Comment: Yeah, so in your `viewWillAppear/Did` you can just reset the position. Or you can use the contentOffset in `UIScrollView`. There are a few other ways around it, but those are the most common I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

The big margin size is navigation bar height, try add a top autolayout for your scrollView.

Comment: Can you say more detailedly? Thanks.